# Send multiple SMS text messages in Phonegap or Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

http://javatechig.com/phonegap/phonegap-sms-plugin-android

Please, this is very important, so important I will set a bounty to the person who answers this question the best.

Anyways, with the script in the URL in the provided, how would I set this so that you could send the same message to many text addresses, multiple text addresses but *not* in a group message header; in other words, send the same message separately to many different people.

Thanks so much :)

Note that I would be cool with having different `input` fields, which you could enter phone numbers in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Markup:

```
<div>
    <input type="tel" id="phoneNumbers" />
    <input type="text" id="message" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.each($('#phoneNumbers').val().split(/[ ,]+/)), function (phoneNumber) {
        SmsPlugin.prototype.send(phoneNumber, message, '');
    });
});
```

The `phoneNumbers` field supports separating phone numbers by commas, whitespace, and comma + whitespace. For example this should work:

> 111111111, 222222222,333333333 444444444, 55555555

Comment: Holy derp. Thats freakin' awesome. You're getting a bounty tomorrow.

Comment: Wait, did he really get the bounty or was that a bunch of hot air?

Comment: I didn't get a bounty ;)

Comment: he'll never give you that bounty ;-)

Comment: Nope, hopefully you'll get some bounty if you make a mess though

Comment: No way I could let this go a full year after a broken promise.  Helped me out, too.